# How to build the below horizontal scroll UI in Flutter where the bottom line with levels should be scrollable along the line

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Design represents a journey like UX where the levels(stars and profile pic) should be scrollable left and right along the line but the image above the line is not scrollable.[image]

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, and generally it's best practice on SO to include some code & what you've tried already rather than just asking people to build your entire UI for you. I'd recommend giving a few things a try and then if you get stuck on specific parts, asking about that i.e. are you having problems with scrolling the profile pic, or the curved clip area, etc.